# SAS Data Step Vs Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I need to create a decision tree (coded) in python. in sas it will be something like this

assuming a data set named original with three columns c1, c2, c3

```
data temp;
set original;
if c1 > 10 and c2 < 6 then res = c1*c2;
else 
  if c3 < 27 or c2 > 9 then res = 6.3;
  else if c1 > 57 or c3 > 38 then res = 10;
    else res = 0;
run;
```

this will create  a a dataset named temp with same columns as original plus a column "res" with appropriate values for each row of the table (depending on the values of c1, c2, c3 for each row)

I tried something like this in python:

```
temp = original
if ((temp['c1'] > 10) & (temp['c2'] < 6)):
  temp['res'] = temp['c1']*temp['c2']
else:  
  if ((temp['c3'] < 27) | (temp['c2'] > 9)):
    temp['res'] = 6.3
  else:
    if ((temp['c1'] > 57) | (temp['c3'] > 38)):
      temp['res']= 10;
    else:
      temp['res']= 0;
```

It keeps telling me syntax error in the first comparison 
if ((temp['c1'] > 10) & (temp['c2'] < 6)):

How can I do the data comparisons at column level but based on specific comparisons for a constant (or another column)

in sas I don't need to index row and column (as I would do in C) just need to reference the column(s) and the execution is row by row

Any help greatly appreciate it

Martin

Comment: You can use `and` and `or` in python too

Comment: Python and SAS are **completely** different languages. It is best to just leave what you know about SAS entirely behind you and learn Python on its own terms. Note, `temp = original` does not create a copy, it simply assigns the same object to another name

Comment: Anyway, the syntax error is due to `&&`, which is not an operator in Python. You might mean `&` do to *elementwise* comparison, assuming you are working with `pandas` objects... watch out, though, you probably want to use parentheses due to the precedence of `&`.

Comment: Thank you Juanpa, yes, pandas, and I meant '&'.I have tried with 'and' too, the error is on the comparison. I know sas and python are different and both are good. but I need to represent a decision tree coded in python.

Comment: The above **does not give a syntax error**

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**`numpy.where`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where) for conditional assignment of arrays. Since nested `if/else` is used, run nested conditions:

```
temp['res'] = np.where((temp['c1'] > 10) & (temp['c2'] < 6),
                       temp['c1'] * temp['c2'],
                       np.where((temp['c3'] < 27) | (temp['c2'] > 9),
                                6.3,
                                np.where((temp['c1'] > 57) | (temp['c3'] > 38),
                                         10, 0)
                       )
              )
```

Alternatively, with [**`numpy.select`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
cond_list = [(temp['c1'] > 10) & (temp['c2'] < 6),
             (temp['c3'] < 27) | (temp['c2'] > 9),
             (temp['c1'] > 57) | (temp['c3'] > 38)]

value_list = [temp['c1'] * temp['c2'], 6.3, 10]


temp['res'] = np.select(cond_list, value_list, default=0)
```

Comment: Parfait, Thank you so much!..do you know if there is any limit in terms of nesting np.where's ? (it seems to be the closest to if-else as sas .

Comment: I do not know of any limit. However, generally in programming running too many logical `if` conditions indicates *code smells* and you may be able to refactor with merges and subsets.